# Using Windows FTP client behind strict firewall

Tags: networking, ftp, firewall

There is a software that depends on Windows `ftp.exe` to transfer files. Problem is, the computer that runs it is behind a very strict firewall, it does not work with Active FTP.

Windows FTP only works in Active FTP mode.

I was thinking of this solution. Sending a packet from a chosen port (for example 1027) to port 20 of the server address. The NAT firewall will then allow incoming access from port 20 to 1027. Then, the computer will send a PORT command to the server to inform that the client data port is 1027. The data transfer will then start.

Will it work? How do I make it work with Windows `ftp` program only?

Note: The server I am using is FileZilla FTP Server

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of this solution. Sending a packet from a chosen
>   port(for example, 1027) to port 20 of the server address. The NAT
>   firewall will then allow incoming access from port 20 to 1027. Then,
>   the computer will send a PORT command to the server to inform that the
>   client data port is 1027. The data transfer will then start.

I do not think you can tell `ftp.exe` to use a port of your choice. It sends the `PORT` with a port of its choice. You (the application) do not send it yourself.

> There is an option on the FileZilla Server "Ignore unroutable IPs on
>   PORT command" Should I enable it? Will it solve the problem?

It would help, had the problem be that the client does not know it's external IP address (meaning it sends wrong IP in the `PORT` command). What is actually the case (`10.10.1.239` is local IP address that the server cannot reach), so you need to turn the option on. But you claim the problem is the firewall too. So while the option helps, it does not solve all the problems you have.

---

Obviously the easiest solution would be to reconfigure your firewall to allow the Active mode. That means to open incoming ports in data connection range.

See *my* article [Network Configuration for Active Mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes#active).

You can restrict the rules just for the server IP address. You can even restrict them further to remote port 20 only.

---

The only other idea I have is to develop a fake `ftp.exe` client that uses the Passive mode. It won't be that difficult, if you make use of some FTP client library, and restrict the client's functionality only to that the application really uses.